# paypal integration types confusion

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I new to paypal integration in asp.net . I found very difficult to understand the paypal api .

I under stood two types -

1. inline html form ( i.e is also called buy button )
2. payflow api

my questions are  :

1. which one must be used for recurring payment ( subcription packages for end user)?
2. in first type , few sites suggested to use IPN for confirmation of payment. I want to know is it neccessary since without using IPN, also using notify_url we can confirm the payment success (as per my knowledge notify_url returns to your site when payment is completed at paypal site)?
3. for recurring payment , do i need to store user account details (i.e credt card or paypal account ) in my databas?

please do reply with you suggestion .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  You can do it with both, actually.  If you want to stick with basic HTML forms then you'd be using Payments Standard, and they call it "Subscriptions".  You can easily create a Subscription button from within your PayPal account.

If you're using the API then they call it Recurring Payments (or Recurring Billing).  You would use Express Checkout for the PayPal signups, and Payments Pro if you want to handle credit cards directly on your site without any redirect to PayPal.

IPN is useful regardless of what integration method you're using, however, don't get it confused with PDT.  PDT sends data back to your site's thank you page, or whatever final page you setup for it, and it only works with Payments Standard.  When PDT is configured on Payments Standard, even with Auto-Return enabled, there is no guarantee the user will make it back to your return URL.  IPN is very similar, but data will always be POSTed to your IPN listener regardless of whether or not the user makes it back to your site.

You'll also want to use IPN to handle updates for future payments on a subscription / recurring profile.  For example, the actual payments, cancelations, suspensions, reactivations, etc.

The notify_url parameter you mentioned is used for IPN.  Again, though, this is separate from PDT.  A common mistake I've seen many times is when people have their PDT and IPN both set to the same URL.  Then when people do make it back to your thank you page, the code actually runs twice.  Once from the user actually hitting it, and once again from PayPal's IPN server hitting it.  So make sure to avoid that sort of thing.

3)  No, you will never save credit card details to your server.  The subscription / recurring system handles that using the data that PayPal saves on their servers.